# Unable to create Enterprise application in NetBeans IDE 12.6

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-12

When I try to create an Enterprise application using the wizard (Ant project) I get the following error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.dd.api.application.Application.setDisplayName(String)" because "this.application" is null
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.earproject.ProjectEar.setupDDFromVirtual(ProjectEar.java:290)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.earproject.ProjectEar.getApplication(ProjectEar.java:255)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.earproject.ui.wizards.NewEarProjectWizardIterator.testableInstantiate(NewEarProjectWizardIterator.java:160)
at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.earproject.ui.wizards.NewEarProjectWizardIterator.instantiate(NewEarProjectWizardIterator.java:139)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard$InstantiatingIteratorBridge.instantiate(TemplateWizard.java:1048)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.handleInstantiate(TemplateWizard.java:602)
at org.netbeans.modules.project.ui.NewProjectWizard.handleInstantiate(NewProjectWizard.java:51)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizard.instantiateNewObjects(TemplateWizard.java:436)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIterImpl.instantiate(TemplateWizardIterImpl.java:228)
at org.openide.loaders.TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper$ProgressInstantiatingIterator.instantiate(TemplateWizardIteratorWrapper.java:155)
at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiateOpen(WizardDescriptor.java:1602)
at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.callInstantiate(WizardDescriptor.java:1546)
at org.openide.WizardDescriptor.access$2300(WizardDescriptor.java:67)
[catch] at org.openide.WizardDescriptor$Listener$2$1.run(WizardDescriptor.java:2233)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:1418)
at org.netbeans.modules.openide.util.GlobalLookup.execute(GlobalLookup.java:45)
at org.openide.util.lookup.Lookups.executeWith(Lookups.java:278)
at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:2033)
```

Of course, all the fields in the wizard are filled. However, there are no errors when creating WAR and EJB separately. The error occurs only when an EAR is created, even if it is empty.

use

- NetBeans 12.6
- Windows 10 OS
- GlassFish Server 6.2.1
- Java 17

All paths are spelled out correctly, read / write permissions to directories are set

[Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/99Bdx.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your problem, and [NetBeans Bug Report 5953](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-5953) *"Creating a new Enterprise Application (Java with Ant) impossible (only when selecting JakartaEE9) - NPEs thrown"* has already been raised.

The bug report is unresolved, but the problem only occurs when creating a Jakarta EE 9 Enterprise Application. I successfully created a Jakarta EE 8 Enterprise Application simply by selecting *Jakarta EE8* from the **Java EE Version** drop list within the wizard.

You have several options available to resolve this, but none of them are good:

- Wait for NetBeans to fix the problem. Definitely not recommended!
- Create a Jakarta EE8 Enterprise Application with the Ant wizard instead, if you don't require EE 9 functionality.
- Create a Jakarta EE8 Enterprise Application with the Ant wizard, then "hack" the generated projects to use EE 9.
- Use another IDE which properly supports this functionality.
- Create the EE 9 Enterprise Application in another IDE, then import the projects into NetBeans.

Using Maven or Gradle isnstead of Ant as the build tool doesn't help either:

- I couldn't create a Maven Enterprise Application when using Jakarta EE8 or Jakarta EE9, though I didn't research why.
- The project wizard doesn't even offer *"Enterprise Application"* as an option when using Gradle.

Notes:

- NetBeans 13 will be released next month, but I don't think this issue will be fixed.
- Also see the (ominous) bug report ["NETBEANS-2871 Resolve Enterprise Application support"](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-2871) from 2019 which remains unresolved:

> Need to figure out whether maybe Web Applications (in Ant, Maven, and
> Gradle) might not be enough in terms of Java EE support, i.e., do we
> need Enterprise Applications and EJB-specific project types, if not,
> let's remove them.

Comment: I confirm everything you said, so far the only working option is, as you noticed, to create Jakarta EE8

Comment: also this problem was seen in 12.5, it is likely that all versions of NetBeans which Jakarta 9 support have this problem

Comment: @JhonFagen Yes, I think you are right - NetBeans doesn't seem to allow the creation of an Enterprise Application when using EE 9, regardless of the NetBeans version. And from reading the comments in some of the bugs raised, it doesn't look like the issue will ever be fixed. Instead, I suspect that the option to create Enterprise Applications through the Project Wizard will be removed eventually. Of course you can keep using NetBeans and manually fix any issues arising yourself, but at some point you might want to consider using another IDE if Enterprise Applications are important for you.

Comment: This problem, as well as its protracted solution, does not mean that NetBeans will no longer support EE9 in the future. If the community had plans to remove EE9 support and enterprise applications in general, this would be announced in some messages and not by creating bugs

Comment: @JhonFagen What??? You completely misread and misunderstood my comment. I said absolutely nothing about NetBeans not supporting EE 9! To be clear, I have said: [1] I doubt if NetBeans will ever fix the bug in the Project Wizard that won't allow the creation of Enterprise Applications that use EE 9. [2] I suspect that the Project Wizard will eventually stop supporting the creation of Enterprise Applications. I never said anything about NetBeans not supporting EE 9.

Answer (score 0):

It works with jakarta EE9 provided you do the following:

Plugin versions in all pom.xml files:

maven-compiler-plugin 3.9.0

maven-war-plugin      3.3.2

maven-dependency-plugin 3.2.0

In the pom.xml file of -ejb-  change packaging war to jar.

Then:

Clean and build in the following order:

top, ejb, web and ear.

That's all.